# How do I reset my "home" location in my Google maps/ system?

Tags: settings

I would like to reset my home location in my maps/nav system to a more accurate GPS position.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To edit your home or work location in Google Maps, follow steps below:

1. Open Google Maps.
2. When opened swipe from the left.
3. Tap "Settings"
4. Tap "Edit home or work"
5. Here you can edit your home or work address in Google Maps.

Hope my answer helped.